# User Input to HTML Tag output

Tags: javascript, html

Ok an example of what i am trying.

User input: http://google.com

I want the output to be:

```html
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.

  $("#change-it").click(function() {
    var userLink = $('#usr-input').val().replace(/.*?:\/\//g, "");
    $('#users-text').text('<a href="' + userLink + '" ><img src="rainbow.gif"></a>');
    $('#user-link').attr('href', 'http://' + userLink);
  });

});
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr-input">
<br>
<button id="change-it" type="button">Update Text</button> 
<br>
<div id="users-text"></div>
<br>
<a id="user-link" href="#" target="_blank">
  <img src="http://orig09.deviantart.net/8364/f/2014/053/f/9/free_space_galaxy_texture_by_lyshastra-d77gofi.png" />
</a>
```

How can i do this with Javascript?

Regards.

Comment: How's the output related to the input?

Comment: I want to have another line that apears when submit is clicked where it shows the above code to the user

Comment: So you want a text input field where the user types a url, and then an image appears which, when clicked, redirects to that url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want the users input to be set as the href on the link as below?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.

  $("#change-it").click(function() {
    var userLink = $('#usr-input').val().replace(/.*?:\/\//g, "");
    $('#users-text').text('<a href="' + userLink + '" ><img src="rainbow.gif"></a>');
    $('#user-link').attr('href', 'http://' + userLink);
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr-input">
<br>
<button id="change-it" type="button">Update Text</button> 
<br>
<div id="users-text"></div>
<br>
<a id="user-link" href="#" target="_blank">
  <img src="http://orig09.deviantart.net/8364/f/2014/053/f/9/free_space_galaxy_texture_by_lyshastra-d77gofi.png" />
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can a user submit there link to the image above?

Comment: Input was below image, moved it to be above.

Comment: I believe stackoverflow is blocking the link from opening here, but you can right click and open in new window.

Comment: Oke thanks this i what i mean only i want the 
<a href="User-Input"><img src="rainbow.gif"></a> like the text. So users can place it on a forum or something.

Comment: Yeah but with mouse right click and open in new window is does work

Comment: Uhmm i am really noob but... it is not working on my .html page?

Comment: Did you include jquery? <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: And is it possible to add a <input type="submit" id="Submit"> to the instead of enter?

Comment: Yes just copied your whole code and set <script></script> by the Document

Comment: Absolutely, it's currently changing on text change in the input but will add a button.

Comment: Can you add your current html below your original post? Will find out why it's not working for you. Make sure it appears inside the document.ready block as well.

Comment: Done just the same text online with the script brackets because it gives an error otherwise.

Comment: Put the script linking to jquery above the script with jquery in it. Should work then. Basically, you are trying to use jquery before it's available.

Answer (score 0):

First get the element i.e. by it's ID:
var element = document.getElementById("element id")

Then change the href property:
element.href = " your string"